# characters allowed on CQ5 file name

Tags: aem, jcr, sling

When uploading a file(an image to the dam folder as an example) on CQ5 using CRXDE lite or other UI interface, the system would give an error message if the file being uploaded has invalid characters.

I just found out that `[` and `]` are not allowed as part of file names.

But when uploading file using a non-UI interface, `SlingPostServlet` for example, the character `[` gets replaced with the percent encoding representation(%5D) and no error was  generated.

Is there some kind of list/doc that would show which characters are not allowed in CQ5?

I am using CQ5.4

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JCR naming restrictions are described in the [Repository Model](http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/2.0/3_Repository_Model.html#3.2.4%20Naming%20Restrictions) section of the JCR specification.

Specifically,  the following characters are not allowed:

```
(“/”, “:”, “[“, “]”, “|”, “*”)
```

There is a com.day.cq.commons.jcr.JcrUtil class has a [createValidName(title)](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/jcr/JcrUtil.html#createValidName%28java.lang.String%29) method which may be able to help you.  By default the `STANDARD_LABEL_CHAR_MAPPING` will replace all illegal characters with an underscore.  It is possible to use the `HYPHEN_LABEL_CHAR_MAPPING` to replace with a hyphen using the [createValidName(title, labelCharMapping[])](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/jcr/JcrUtil.html#createValidName%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

Clientlibs used by the coral-ui on AEM's backend use the following regex to filter:

**_ILLEGAL_FILENAME_REGEX: /[\".%/\:*?[]|\n\t\r ]|[\x7f-\uffff]/g**

Here's a sample:

```js
var text = "äüö?abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!\"§$%&/()=?´`+*#'-_.:,;<>^°";
var regex = /[\"\.%/\\:*?\[\]|\n\t\r ]|[\x7f-\uffff]/g;
console.log(text.toLowerCase().replace(regex, '-'));
```